# Android XML| Understanding the pathData syntax

Tags: android, xml, vector, android-vectordrawable

So i am trying to understand the pathData syntax in order to create some vector drawables via xml...

I am able to create any square shapes, but i just can't understand how to create circular shapes (such as oval or a circle).

could anyone give some examples of circular shapes:

1. Circle.
2. Oval.
3. Empty Circle/Oval (putting it on another shape will cause this part to be transparent).

with explanation to what each pathData attribute does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Notes on Paths (SVG notation used in anroid-vectordrawable) : Paths have a compact coding. For example **M** (for 'move to') precedes initial numeric x and y coordinates and **L** (line to) precedes a point to which a line should be drawn. Further command letters (**C**, **S**, **Q**, **T** and **A**) precede data that is used to draw various Bézier and elliptical curves. **Q** is quadratic Bézier, **Z** is used to close a path. In all cases, absolute coordinates follow capital letter commands and relative coordinates are used after the equivalent lower-case letters.
 [SVG path notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).
**Command**    :**A** (absolute)**a** (relative)
**Name**       :elliptical arc
**Parameters** :(rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y)+
**Description**:Draws an elliptical arc from the current point to
        (**x**, **y**). The size and
        orientation of the ellipse are defined by two radii
        (**rx**, **ry**) and an
        **x-axis-rotation**, which indicates how the
        ellipse as a whole is rotated relative to the current
        coordinate system. The center (**cx**,
        **cy**) of the ellipse is calculated
        automatically to satisfy the constraints imposed by the
        other parameters. **large-arc-flag** and
        **sweep-flag** contribute to the automatic
        calculations and help determine how the arc is drawn.

Use this (`circle.xml`), in your `res/drawable` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportHeight="64"
    android:viewportWidth="64">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#ff0000"
        android:pathData="M22,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 42,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 22,32 Z" />
</vector>

Parameters :(rx, ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag, sweep-flag x,  y )

            (10, 10       0               1,            1     42, 32 )
            (10, 10       0               1,            1     22, 32 )
```

**NOTE**:Superfluous white space and separators such as commas can be eliminated.
Two arc's make a circle.
Circle is a special case of oval, android:fillColor="@color/transparent".

Comment: @cricket_007 it's from https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData and the link is in the text " SVG path notation".

Answer (score -3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:viewportHeight="108"
    android:viewportWidth="108">

    <!--right half circle -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E1261D"
        android:pathData="M54,0
        A54,54 0 1,1 54,108Z" />

    <!--left half circle -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#E1261D"
        android:pathData="M54,108
        A54,54 0 1,1 54,0Z" />
</vector>
```

or else

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportWidth="108"
    android:viewportHeight="108">


    <path
        android:fillColor="#E1261D"
        android:pathData="M54,0
        A54,54 0 1,1 53.99999,0Z" />


</vector>
```

Comment: This answer neither explains all the magic numbers nor does it link to any further information. It also doesn't add any value over the existing answer.